# How to install extension for ckan-docker (saml2auth)

Tags: docker, ckan

I am trying to install saml2auth in my ckan docker 2.10 instance. I am quite new to the docker world, so I don't know if I am doing it correctly. I usually entered the bash console in the running container by using the command docker exec -it ckan /bin/bash. Then I installed the required packages with pip. However, for saml2auth I need to use apt for xmlsec1. When I try to execute the command 'apt install xmlsec1' it tells me bash: apt: command not found. What is the correct way to install this extension in ckan docker?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] showing what you've done so far?  You should almost never try to install software in a `docker exec` shell: that work will be lost as soon as the container exits.